# Android studio sometimes lags when scrolling

Tags: android, android-studio, lag

I scroll a lot when looking at code in Android studio and most often scrolling works well. But sometimes it stucks and have to wait about 10s to be able to scroll again. Is there any solution to this problem or maybe anybody experience the same? My PC specs:
[image]

Comment: Typically Android Studio requires at least 1TB of RAM in order to run smoothly. /s

Comment: what else you expect from this machine? I have 7th gen gaming machine and it still sometime lags.

Comment: Hmm... Very sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried increasing maximum heap size?
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

Comment: Thank you, I set everything to be 2GB and I couldn't say I got rid of lag fully but at least I don't experience 10s delays now.